# how to round a number to the nearest multiple of 64

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that creates a square on top of a tile in a tile map. The tiles are 64 by 64. I was thinking that I need to get the coordinates of the mouse, round it to the nearest multiple of 64, and divide that by 64 to get the tile coordinate. Is there a better way? Should I make all of the tiles buttons? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
int number = 445226;
int roundoff = (number+0x20)&(~0x3f);
```

It works as follows:

1. You first add `32` (`0x20`) to the number so that it is rounded up/down. This means everything below `32` will result in a value less than `64` and everything larger than `32` to a value larger than `64`.
2. You mask out the last six bits.

In general bitwise operations are faster than division and multiplication. And since you ask for a power of two, it's a nice performance hack you can use.

But if you are interested in tile coordinate, you don't have to multiply it again by `64` I guess. In that case you can use:

```
int number = 445226;
int div64 = (number+0x20)>>0x06; //this is divided by 64, not rounded
```

About the user interface, as always mutliple answers are correct, but if you're going to paint some kind of map on it, I guess coordinates are better than buttons. Especially if later in the process, people will be able to click on items on the map that lie between two buttons.

Answer (score 2):

For positive integers:

```
int m64 = 64 * ((n + 32) / 64);
```

Or more fancy because 64 happens to be a power of 2:

```
int m64 = ((n + 32) >> 6) << 6;
```

Comment: Here you divide it by 64, you need to round it. And the division by `64` can be done more efficiently by shifting...

Comment: Why does he need to round it? Doesn't an integer operation round to the nearest unit?

Comment: @JClassic no. Integer arithmetic *trucates*, like calling  `floor()`, eg `9/10 -> 0`, which is not rounding to the nearest integer, but the next integer below the division result.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Firstly, adding 32 to the dividend before doing truncating integer division by 64 produces *rounding* division. Secondly, no, it cannot be done more efficiently by shifting. There's no difference in efficiency when the divisor is a known constant.